Why my filesystem is full and what should i do here?
My file system is getting full often. Kindly help me. I have increased my GB to 128 today.
loop0      7:0    0  25.2M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/7983
loop1      7:1    0  25.2M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/7993
loop2      7:2    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2812
loop3      7:3    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2823
loop4      7:4    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2264
loop5      7:5    0  63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2318
loop6      7:6    0    87M  1 loop /snap/lxd/28373
loop7      7:7    0    87M  1 loop /snap/lxd/27948
loop8      7:8    0  38.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21465
loop10     7:10   0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
xvda     202:0    0   128G  0 disk 
├─xvda1  202:1    0 127.9G  0 part /
├─xvda14 202:14   0     4M  0 part 
└─xvda15 202:15   0   106M  0 part /boot/efi


Try the linked question, if it doesn't help let us know, it might be something specific to your installation
